# AWS Robomaker - success story?

Tags: simulation

I've struggled to get my head around Robomaker and still have not gotten even a simple robotic example to work. Have you located any documentation that is more complete than one Amazon offers?

Answer (score 4):

I'm a product manager from the AWS RoboMaker team. We have a tutorial that can help you get started with the service: [Projects on AWS:
How to Train a Robot Using Reinforcement Learning
with AWS RoboMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/robomaker/resources/train-a-robot-using-reinforcement-learning-project/)

If you have any questions or feedback for the service, please reach out to me and I would love to help and take your feedback to improve our service.

Comment: Email addresses aren't really permitted in posts, I'm afraid, see [What to do if user inadvertently includes email in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61031/what-to-do-if-user-inadvertently-includes-email-in-a-post) and [Are support personnel email addresses allowed in answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328048/are-support-personnel-email-addresses-allowed-in-answers)